# Mean Excess function of the normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution

In preparation of my upcoming finals I am trying to calculate the mean excess functions of some common distributions. In this case I am working on the normal distribution. I can calculate it for the standard normal distribution, however the general case isn't as simple. 
To calculate it for the standard normal distribution I assume $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $u \in (-\infty,\infty)$ and calculate:
\begin{align*}
e_1(u)=&E(X-u\left|X>u\right.)\\=&\frac{\int_u^\infty(x-u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}{\bar{\Phi}(u)}\\
=&\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_u^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx-u\cdot\bar{\Phi}(u)}{\bar{\Phi}(u)}\\
=&\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}}{\bar{\Phi}(u)}-u\\
=&\frac{\phi(u)}{\bar{\Phi}(u)}-u
\end{align*}
Now if we let $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ then
$$
e_2(u)=E(Y-u\left|Y>u\right.)=\frac{\int_u^\infty \frac{(x-u)}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx}{\bar{\Phi}(\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma})}
$$
From here I can't seem to get anything nice from the integral. Perhaps I should instead I should focus on expanding the first result into something along the lines of the following?
$$
e_2(u)=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi(\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma})}{\bar{\Phi}(\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma})}-u
$$
However I can't come up with any formal argument why this should be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write $Y=\mu+\sigma X$ where $X$ has standard normal distribution.

Then: $$\mathsf E(Y-u\mid Y>u)=\mathsf E(\sigma X+\mu-u\mid \sigma X+\mu>u)=\sigma\mathsf E(X-\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma}\mid X>\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma})$$